# Memory leak in applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am having around 9 `ViewControllers` in my application. I am opening the ViewControllers using the `presentModalViewController`. I want to display the 1st ViewController every time the user enters background and comes to foreground. If the user enters background in 8th ViewController and opens the application again , I need to display the 1st View Controller.

I am using the following code in the `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.HomeScreenViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = _homeScreenViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and it is showing a memory leak. Obviously it will show the memory leak since I am initializing the HomeCtrl again, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me ??
I am not using the `UINavigationController` since the ViewControllers are pushed from right or Left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
self.HomeScreenViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] ....];
```

to

```
_HomeScreenViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] ....];
```

Or you can do something like follow code:

```
HomeScreenViewController *tempHSVC = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] ....];
self.HomeScreenViewController = tempHSVC;
[tempHSVC release];
self.window.rootViewController = self.HomeScreenViewController //or use just _homeScreenViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And read some articles about memory management in objc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume HomeScreenViewController property is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) HomeScreenViewController *HomeScreenViewController
```

Default setter method for retained properties will retain the object for you. Add autorelease to alloc init:

```
self.HomeScreenViewController = [[[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

See also: [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)